# Dang Error #1009 !

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I'm building a simple flash site for a friend who has a spa.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at spa7_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

through the process of commenting out code, i've narrowed down to my link section:

```
vox_link.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoVox);
function gotoVox(evtObj:Event):void {
    var voxSite:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://www.voxmundiproject.com");
    navigateToURL(voxSite, "_blank");
}
```

With this section commented out, i don't get the 1009 error. When the code is active,
I get the error.

My code syntax is correct so I'm stumped.

Does someone have an idea what my be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you are using an object (accessing methods/properties) that is null. From what I see, it's probably **vox_link** that is null here or does not exist.

Comment: yep, seems that's the problem. try `trace(vox_link)`

Comment: ahhhh! i'm learning. the script for the links page was on frame one.... not the frame where the links actually were. i moved the code to the frame where my link buttons are and it seemed to fix the problem.

i can not have code in frame one for an object that lives in another frame... or is there a way to have all my code in the same frame?

Comment: I suppose you could put your "click" handler functions (gotoVox) in frame 1. And do the addEventListener() calls when the buttons already exist.

Comment: But what would be so much better in terms of code manageability is to learn how to code "outside" the timeline: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash/

Answer (score 0):

THis is a very late response XD but try URLLoader instead of URLRequest